# How does this constructor work?

Tags: java, constructor

I cannot understand how this constructor works:

```
public class Multiply {
    //and here i've got this atypical for me constuctor
    Multiply mult(Multiply a){
        Multiply tmp;
        //code here
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a method, not a constructor. A constructor can never ever return something.

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor here, in your case a default constructor will take place, and an instance of the class without any special operation will perform on the 'new'  word

Answer (score 0):

A constructor has the same name as the class and no return type. What you have right there is a method called `mult` with the return type `Multiply`. You might be confused because the visbility modfier is missing. This is totally valid as the default visibility `protected` is used in this case.

It's the same as:

```
protected Multiply mult(Multiply a)
```

A constructor would look like this:

```
public Multiply(Multiply a)
```

If no constructor is declared, the default constructor is implicitly added to your class. So the class has a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Multiply() {
    super();
}
```